# Access SVG parts and use them in HTML <img> tag

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="841.89px" height="1190.551px" viewBox="0 0 841.89 1190.551" enable-background="new 0 0 841.89 1190.551"
     xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="#9D9E9E" stroke-width="0.5" points="285.08,348.066 526.791,348.066 526.791,420.576 
    285.08,420.576 "/>
<g id="_677331264">
    <polygon fill="#264796" points="360.624,402.123 330.803,402.123 330.803,375.789 360.624,375.789     "/>
    <path fill="#D52339" d="M356.74,365.103c0,1.757-1.417,3.175-3.146,3.175c-1.758,0-3.146-1.418-3.146-3.175
        c0-1.758,1.389-3.175,3.146-3.175C355.323,361.928,356.74,363.345,356.74,365.103z"/>
    <path fill="#FEFEFE" d="M336.047,386.759c2.354-1.871,5.046-3.543,7.54-3.997c2.155-0.368,4.025,0.341,4.848,2.296
        c0.964,2.297,0.596,5.585-0.312,8.816c-1.219,4.507-3.458,9.155-6.123,13.492c-0.028,0.058-0.085,0.114-0.113,0.171
        c0.794-0.652,1.559-1.361,2.296-2.098c3.771-3.686,7.059-8.164,9.524-12.87c2.098-3.968,3.6-8.135,3.884-11.905
        c0.198-2.806-0.397-5.386-2.268-6.633c-1.729-1.162-4.28-0.851-6.719,0.17c-2.92,1.219-5.782,3.43-8.306,5.812
        c-2.976,2.834-5.697,6.236-7.993,9.864c-0.142,0.198-0.255,0.396-0.369,0.596C333.241,389.14,334.63,387.865,336.047,386.759z"/>
    <path fill="#264796" d="M336.132,386.844c2.863-2.268,5.358-3.6,7.484-3.969c2.211-0.396,3.939,0.426,4.705,2.211
        c0.822,2.013,0.737,4.961-0.312,8.76c-1.162,4.224-3.231,8.759-6.123,13.464c-0.028,0.057-0.057,0.114-0.113,0.171l0.198,0.142
        c0.766-0.624,1.53-1.333,2.296-2.098c3.714-3.629,7.03-8.107,9.553-12.897c2.296-4.338,3.629-8.447,3.884-11.935
        c0.255-3.203-0.567-5.584-2.296-6.746c-1.616-1.077-4.054-1.021-6.86,0.142c-2.607,1.105-5.414,3.062-8.334,5.84
        c-2.891,2.749-5.669,6.179-8.021,9.893l-0.369,0.595l0.199,0.143C333.383,389.168,334.771,387.921,336.132,386.844z
         M332.051,390.53l0.368-0.567c2.324-3.713,5.103-7.115,7.994-9.864c2.891-2.75,5.641-4.706,8.248-5.783
        c2.722-1.134,5.046-1.19,6.576-0.17c1.673,1.105,2.438,3.43,2.212,6.52c-0.256,3.459-1.588,7.54-3.855,11.849
        c-2.522,4.791-5.812,9.213-9.496,12.842c-0.766,0.765-1.53,1.445-2.296,2.098l0.198,0.142c0.028-0.057,0.057-0.113,0.113-0.17
        c2.92-4.706,4.989-9.27,6.151-13.521c1.049-3.855,1.162-6.86,0.283-8.901c-0.822-1.927-2.636-2.777-4.989-2.353
        c-2.183,0.368-4.648,1.701-7.597,4.025c-1.36,1.077-2.749,2.324-4.11,3.713L332.051,390.53z"/>
    <path fill="#264796" d="M391.918,378.255l4.45,21.94h-5.556l-2.664-16.385c-0.426,2.552-2.325,16.385-2.325,16.385h-5.641
        l4.422-21.94H391.918z"/>
    <polygon fill="#264796" points="409.067,390.983 404.107,390.983 404.107,395.915 409.691,395.915 409.691,400.281 
        398.863,400.281 398.863,378.368 409.323,378.368 409.323,382.734 404.107,382.734 404.107,386.816 409.067,386.816     "/>
    <path fill="#264796" d="M411.846,378.51c1.445-0.312,3.458-0.453,5.612-0.453c2.126,0,4.393,0.198,6.124,1.587
        c1.332,1.049,1.842,2.608,1.842,4.167c0,1.843-0.963,3.771-3.23,4.791v0.142c2.635,0.766,3.967,2.892,3.967,5.131
        c0,1.842-0.623,3.26-1.699,4.337c-1.389,1.445-3.799,2.353-8.165,2.353c-1.7,0-3.316-0.113-4.45-0.283V378.51z M417.062,387.156
        h0.851c1.417,0,2.353-1.19,2.353-2.777c0-1.446-0.709-2.552-2.098-2.552c-0.453,0-0.822,0.028-1.105,0.142V387.156z
         M417.062,396.595c0.283,0.085,0.566,0.085,0.851,0.085c1.445,0,2.806-0.906,2.806-2.862c0-1.899-1.304-2.92-2.749-2.92h-0.907
        V396.595z"/>
    <path fill="#D52339" d="M439.625,378.425v3.515c0,4.11-0.34,8.277-0.48,10.035h0.084c0.51-1.673,1.672-4.507,2.211-5.896
        l3.006-7.653h4.648v21.742h-4.508v-3.742c0-4.252,0.199-7.71,0.283-9.581h-0.057c-0.396,1.616-1.416,4.337-2.068,6.01l-2.92,7.313
        h-4.762v-21.742H439.625z"/>
    <polygon fill="#D52339" points="456.802,378.425 456.802,386.872 460.63,386.872 460.63,378.425 465.818,378.425 465.818,400.167 
        460.63,400.167 460.63,391.522 456.802,391.522 456.802,400.167 451.617,400.167 451.617,378.425   "/>
    <path fill="#D52339" d="M480.615,399.6c-0.596,0.255-2.098,0.624-3.658,0.624c-6.377,0-8.928-5.131-8.928-10.771
        c0-8.022,4.848-11.452,9.553-11.452c1.615,0,1.898,0.142,3.061,0.34v4.309c-1.162-0.368-2.182-0.51-3.061-0.453
        c-2.551,0.17-4.961,2.154-4.961,7.001c0,4.536,2.721,6.548,5.357,6.548c0.623,0,2.098-0.198,2.637-0.34V399.6z"/>
    <path fill="#264796" d="M384.18,369.071c0.312-0.227,0.708-0.368,1.219-0.368c0.822,0,1.36,0.425,1.36,1.19
        c0,0.596-0.396,1.049-0.936,1.19l0,0c0.652,0.085,1.134,0.511,1.134,1.219c0,1.021-0.85,1.418-1.7,1.418
        c-0.426,0-0.851-0.085-1.219-0.313l0.17-0.51c0.255,0.17,0.651,0.312,1.049,0.312c0.68,0,1.049-0.396,1.049-0.936
        c0-0.708-0.652-0.936-1.247-0.936h-0.284v-0.481h0.284c0.595,0,1.077-0.396,1.077-0.879c0-0.51-0.341-0.766-0.822-0.766
        c-0.34,0-0.709,0.143-0.964,0.313L384.18,369.071z M384.18,369.071c0.312-0.227,0.708-0.368,1.219-0.368
        c0.822,0,1.36,0.425,1.36,1.19c0,0.596-0.396,1.049-0.936,1.19l0,0c0.652,0.085,1.134,0.511,1.134,1.219
        c0,1.021-0.85,1.418-1.7,1.418c-0.426,0-0.851-0.085-1.219-0.313l0.17-0.51c0.255,0.17,0.651,0.312,1.049,0.312
        c0.68,0,1.049-0.396,1.049-0.936c0-0.708-0.652-0.936-1.247-0.936h-0.284v-0.481h0.284c0.595,0,1.077-0.396,1.077-0.879
        c0-0.51-0.341-0.766-0.822-0.766c-0.34,0-0.709,0.143-0.964,0.313L384.18,369.071z M390.019,371.622l-0.453-1.418
        c-0.113-0.312-0.17-0.595-0.227-0.878h-0.028c-0.057,0.283-0.142,0.595-0.228,0.878l-0.453,1.418H390.019z M388.488,372.104
        l-0.482,1.531h-0.595l1.559-4.876h0.737l1.588,4.876h-0.652l-0.511-1.531H388.488z M390.019,371.622l-0.453-1.418
        c-0.113-0.312-0.17-0.595-0.227-0.878h-0.028c-0.057,0.283-0.142,0.595-0.228,0.878l-0.453,1.418H390.019z M388.488,372.104
        l-0.482,1.531h-0.595l1.559-4.876h0.737l1.588,4.876h-0.652l-0.511-1.531H388.488z M395.093,373.464
        c-0.198,0.143-0.651,0.256-1.219,0.256c-1.304,0-2.296-0.879-2.296-2.467c0-1.53,0.992-2.551,2.438-2.551
        c0.567,0,0.936,0.113,1.105,0.198l-0.17,0.539c-0.198-0.142-0.538-0.228-0.907-0.228c-1.105,0-1.814,0.737-1.814,2.013
        c0,1.19,0.652,1.956,1.758,1.956c0.368,0,0.766-0.085,0.992-0.198L395.093,373.464z M395.093,373.464
        c-0.198,0.143-0.651,0.256-1.219,0.256c-1.304,0-2.296-0.879-2.296-2.467c0-1.53,0.992-2.551,2.438-2.551
        c0.567,0,0.936,0.113,1.105,0.198l-0.17,0.539c-0.198-0.142-0.538-0.228-0.907-0.228c-1.105,0-1.814,0.737-1.814,2.013
        c0,1.19,0.652,1.956,1.758,1.956c0.368,0,0.766-0.085,0.992-0.198L395.093,373.464z M396.992,369.298h-1.417v-0.539h3.43v0.539
        h-1.418v4.337h-0.595V369.298z M396.992,369.298h-1.417v-0.539h3.43v0.539h-1.418v4.337h-0.595V369.298z M400.11,371.168
        c0.142,0.028,0.312,0.057,0.51,0.057c0.709,0,1.162-0.368,1.162-1.049c0-0.623-0.425-0.936-1.105-0.936
        c-0.255,0-0.453,0-0.566,0.028V371.168z M399.515,368.844c0.284-0.057,0.681-0.113,1.162-0.113c0.596,0,1.021,0.142,1.305,0.396
        c0.255,0.228,0.396,0.596,0.396,1.021c0,0.454-0.113,0.794-0.368,1.049c-0.313,0.341-0.822,0.539-1.418,0.539
        c-0.17,0-0.34-0.028-0.481-0.057v1.956h-0.596V368.844z M400.11,371.168c0.142,0.028,0.312,0.057,0.51,0.057
        c0.709,0,1.162-0.368,1.162-1.049c0-0.623-0.425-0.936-1.105-0.936c-0.255,0-0.453,0-0.566,0.028V371.168z M399.515,368.844
        c0.284-0.057,0.681-0.113,1.162-0.113c0.596,0,1.021,0.142,1.305,0.396c0.255,0.228,0.396,0.596,0.396,1.021
        c0,0.454-0.113,0.794-0.368,1.049c-0.313,0.341-0.822,0.539-1.418,0.539c-0.17,0-0.34-0.028-0.481-0.057v1.956h-0.596V368.844z
         M404.872,371.622l-0.453-1.418c-0.085-0.312-0.17-0.595-0.227-0.878h-0.028c-0.057,0.283-0.142,0.595-0.228,0.878l-0.453,1.418
        H404.872z M403.37,372.104l-0.482,1.531h-0.623l1.559-4.876h0.737l1.588,4.876h-0.652l-0.481-1.531H403.37z M404.872,371.622
        l-0.453-1.418c-0.085-0.312-0.17-0.595-0.227-0.878h-0.028c-0.057,0.283-0.142,0.595-0.228,0.878l-0.453,1.418H404.872z
         M403.37,372.104l-0.482,1.531h-0.623l1.559-4.876h0.737l1.588,4.876h-0.652l-0.481-1.531H403.37z M409.352,373.635l-0.596-1.077
        c-0.227-0.397-0.368-0.681-0.51-0.964h-0.028c-0.114,0.283-0.256,0.538-0.511,0.964l-0.538,1.077h-0.709l1.417-2.467l-1.36-2.409
        h0.709l0.595,1.162c0.198,0.312,0.312,0.539,0.454,0.822l0,0c0.142-0.312,0.255-0.511,0.425-0.822l0.624-1.162h0.708l-1.417,2.381
        l1.445,2.495H409.352z M409.352,373.635l-0.596-1.077c-0.227-0.397-0.368-0.681-0.51-0.964h-0.028
        c-0.114,0.283-0.256,0.538-0.511,0.964l-0.538,1.077h-0.709l1.417-2.467l-1.36-2.409h0.709l0.595,1.162
        c0.198,0.312,0.312,0.539,0.454,0.822l0,0c0.142-0.312,0.255-0.511,0.425-0.822l0.624-1.162h0.708l-1.417,2.381l1.445,2.495
        H409.352z M412.413,373.209c0.935,0,1.474-0.936,1.474-2.041c0-0.964-0.482-1.956-1.474-1.956c-0.992,0-1.503,0.964-1.503,2.013
        c0,1.021,0.539,1.984,1.474,1.984H412.413z M412.355,373.72c-1.219,0-2.069-0.992-2.069-2.467c0-1.559,0.907-2.551,2.155-2.551
        c1.275,0,2.068,0.992,2.068,2.438c0,1.673-0.963,2.58-2.126,2.58H412.355z M412.413,373.209c0.935,0,1.474-0.936,1.474-2.041
        c0-0.964-0.482-1.956-1.474-1.956c-0.992,0-1.503,0.964-1.503,2.013c0,1.021,0.539,1.984,1.474,1.984H412.413z M412.355,373.72
        c-1.219,0-2.069-0.992-2.069-2.467c0-1.559,0.907-2.551,2.155-2.551c1.275,0,2.068,0.992,2.068,2.438
        c0,1.673-0.963,2.58-2.126,2.58H412.355z M415.899,373.153c0.113,0.028,0.283,0.028,0.51,0.028c0.624,0,1.19-0.227,1.19-0.936
        c0-0.651-0.538-0.936-1.19-0.936h-0.51V373.153z M415.899,370.828h0.538c0.624,0,1.021-0.34,1.021-0.822
        c0-0.566-0.425-0.794-1.021-0.794c-0.283,0-0.453,0.028-0.538,0.057V370.828z M415.304,368.844
        c0.255-0.057,0.681-0.113,1.105-0.113c0.596,0,0.964,0.113,1.247,0.368c0.256,0.17,0.397,0.454,0.397,0.851
        c0,0.482-0.312,0.879-0.794,1.077l0,0c0.454,0.113,0.964,0.511,0.964,1.219c0,0.426-0.142,0.737-0.396,0.992
        c-0.313,0.313-0.851,0.454-1.588,0.454c-0.425,0-0.737-0.028-0.936-0.057V368.844z M415.899,373.153
        c0.113,0.028,0.283,0.028,0.51,0.028c0.624,0,1.19-0.227,1.19-0.936c0-0.651-0.538-0.936-1.19-0.936h-0.51V373.153z
         M415.899,370.828h0.538c0.624,0,1.021-0.34,1.021-0.822c0-0.566-0.425-0.794-1.021-0.794c-0.283,0-0.453,0.028-0.538,0.057
        V370.828z M415.304,368.844c0.255-0.057,0.681-0.113,1.105-0.113c0.596,0,0.964,0.113,1.247,0.368
        c0.256,0.17,0.397,0.454,0.397,0.851c0,0.482-0.312,0.879-0.794,1.077l0,0c0.454,0.113,0.964,0.511,0.964,1.219
        c0,0.426-0.142,0.737-0.396,0.992c-0.313,0.313-0.851,0.454-1.588,0.454c-0.425,0-0.737-0.028-0.936-0.057V368.844z
         M421.313,371.622l-0.482-1.418c-0.085-0.312-0.142-0.595-0.227-0.878l0,0c-0.085,0.283-0.142,0.595-0.227,0.878l-0.481,1.418
        H421.313z M419.782,372.104l-0.481,1.531h-0.624l1.588-4.876h0.709l1.586,4.876h-0.623l-0.51-1.531H419.782z M421.313,371.622
        l-0.482-1.418c-0.085-0.312-0.142-0.595-0.227-0.878l0,0c-0.085,0.283-0.142,0.595-0.227,0.878l-0.481,1.418H421.313z
         M419.782,372.104l-0.481,1.531h-0.624l1.588-4.876h0.709l1.586,4.876h-0.623l-0.51-1.531H419.782z M423.835,369.298h-1.416v-0.539
        h3.43v0.539h-1.418v4.337h-0.596V369.298z M423.835,369.298h-1.416v-0.539h3.43v0.539h-1.418v4.337h-0.596V369.298z
         M428.769,371.366h-1.787v1.729h1.984v0.539h-2.607v-4.876h2.523v0.539h-1.9v1.53h1.787V371.366z M428.769,371.366h-1.787v1.729
        h1.984v0.539h-2.607v-4.876h2.523v0.539h-1.9v1.53h1.787V371.366z M432.992,368.759v4.876h-0.596v-4.337h-1.529v1.474
        c0,1.049-0.057,2.239-0.709,2.692c-0.17,0.114-0.453,0.228-0.709,0.228l-0.084-0.511c0.197-0.028,0.367-0.142,0.48-0.255
        c0.369-0.368,0.426-1.332,0.426-2.098v-2.069H432.992z M432.992,368.759v4.876h-0.596v-4.337h-1.529v1.474
        c0,1.049-0.057,2.239-0.709,2.692c-0.17,0.114-0.453,0.228-0.709,0.228l-0.084-0.511c0.197-0.028,0.367-0.142,0.48-0.255
        c0.369-0.368,0.426-1.332,0.426-2.098v-2.069H432.992z M434.636,368.759v2.041h2.24v-2.041h0.594v4.876h-0.594v-2.269h-2.24v2.269
        h-0.623v-4.876H434.636z M434.636,368.759v2.041h2.24v-2.041h0.594v4.876h-0.594v-2.269h-2.24v2.269h-0.623v-4.876H434.636z
         M440.787,371.622l-0.453-1.418c-0.084-0.312-0.17-0.595-0.227-0.878h-0.027c-0.057,0.283-0.143,0.595-0.229,0.878l-0.453,1.418
        H440.787z M439.285,372.104l-0.51,1.531h-0.596l1.559-4.876h0.738l1.588,4.876h-0.652l-0.482-1.531H439.285z M440.787,371.622
        l-0.453-1.418c-0.084-0.312-0.17-0.595-0.227-0.878h-0.027c-0.057,0.283-0.143,0.595-0.229,0.878l-0.453,1.418H440.787z
         M439.285,372.104l-0.51,1.531h-0.596l1.559-4.876h0.738l1.588,4.876h-0.652l-0.482-1.531H439.285z M446.173,368.759v2.183h0.199
        l1.586-2.183h0.709l-1.758,2.239c0.766,0.113,1.078,0.596,1.305,1.247c0.17,0.511,0.313,0.964,0.51,1.39h-0.652
        c-0.17-0.341-0.283-0.766-0.424-1.134c-0.199-0.652-0.482-1.106-1.275-1.106h-0.199v2.24h-0.596v-4.876H446.173z M446.173,368.759
        v2.183h0.199l1.586-2.183h0.709l-1.758,2.239c0.766,0.113,1.078,0.596,1.305,1.247c0.17,0.511,0.313,0.964,0.51,1.39h-0.652
        c-0.17-0.341-0.283-0.766-0.424-1.134c-0.199-0.652-0.482-1.106-1.275-1.106h-0.199v2.24h-0.596v-4.876H446.173z M451.021,373.209
        c0.963,0,1.502-0.936,1.502-2.041c0-0.964-0.482-1.956-1.502-1.956c-0.992,0-1.475,0.964-1.475,2.013
        C449.546,372.245,450.085,373.209,451.021,373.209L451.021,373.209z M450.992,373.72c-1.246,0-2.098-0.992-2.098-2.467
        c0-1.559,0.908-2.551,2.154-2.551c1.275,0,2.098,0.992,2.098,2.438C453.146,372.813,452.183,373.72,450.992,373.72L450.992,373.72z
         M451.021,373.209c0.963,0,1.502-0.936,1.502-2.041c0-0.964-0.482-1.956-1.502-1.956c-0.992,0-1.475,0.964-1.475,2.013
        C449.546,372.245,450.085,373.209,451.021,373.209L451.021,373.209z M450.992,373.72c-1.246,0-2.098-0.992-2.098-2.467
        c0-1.559,0.908-2.551,2.154-2.551c1.275,0,2.098,0.992,2.098,2.438C453.146,372.813,452.183,373.72,450.992,373.72L450.992,373.72z
         M457.824,371.509c-0.029-0.681-0.057-1.503-0.057-2.126h-0.029c-0.17,0.566-0.34,1.19-0.566,1.87l-0.822,2.354h-0.453
        l-0.766-2.325c-0.227-0.68-0.396-1.304-0.539-1.898l0,0c-0.027,0.623-0.057,1.445-0.084,2.154l-0.143,2.098h-0.566l0.313-4.876
        h0.766l0.793,2.353c0.199,0.624,0.34,1.162,0.482,1.645l0,0c0.141-0.482,0.311-1.021,0.51-1.645l0.822-2.353h0.766l0.283,4.876
        h-0.596L457.824,371.509z M457.824,371.509c-0.029-0.681-0.057-1.503-0.057-2.126h-0.029c-0.17,0.566-0.34,1.19-0.566,1.87
        l-0.822,2.354h-0.453l-0.766-2.325c-0.227-0.68-0.396-1.304-0.539-1.898l0,0c-0.027,0.623-0.057,1.445-0.084,2.154l-0.143,2.098
        h-0.566l0.313-4.876h0.766l0.793,2.353c0.199,0.624,0.34,1.162,0.482,1.645l0,0c0.141-0.482,0.311-1.021,0.51-1.645l0.822-2.353
        h0.766l0.283,4.876h-0.596L457.824,371.509z M462.812,368.759v4.876h-0.594v-4.337h-2.154v4.337h-0.596v-4.876H462.812z
         M462.812,368.759v4.876h-0.594v-4.337h-2.154v4.337h-0.596v-4.876H462.812z M466.128,371.622l-0.453-1.418
        c-0.084-0.312-0.17-0.595-0.227-0.878h-0.027c-0.057,0.283-0.143,0.595-0.229,0.878l-0.453,1.418H466.128z M464.626,372.104
        l-0.482,1.531h-0.623l1.559-4.876h0.738l1.586,4.876h-0.65l-0.482-1.531H464.626z M466.128,371.622l-0.453-1.418
        c-0.084-0.312-0.17-0.595-0.227-0.878h-0.027c-0.057,0.283-0.143,0.595-0.229,0.878l-0.453,1.418H466.128z M464.626,372.104
        l-0.482,1.531h-0.623l1.559-4.876h0.738l1.586,4.876h-0.65l-0.482-1.531H464.626z M468.681,368.759v2.041h2.238v-2.041h0.623v4.876
        h-0.623v-2.269h-2.238v2.269h-0.596v-4.876H468.681z M468.681,368.759v2.041h2.238v-2.041h0.623v4.876h-0.623v-2.269h-2.238v2.269
        h-0.596v-4.876H468.681z M473.13,368.759v2.069c0,0.766,0,1.389-0.057,2.041l0.029,0.028c0.227-0.539,0.51-1.049,0.85-1.616
        l1.502-2.522h0.596v4.876h-0.566v-2.069c0-0.794,0-1.361,0.057-1.984h-0.029c-0.227,0.538-0.537,1.077-0.85,1.644l-1.445,2.41
        h-0.652v-4.876H473.13z M473.13,368.759v2.069c0,0.766,0,1.389-0.057,2.041l0.029,0.028c0.227-0.539,0.51-1.049,0.85-1.616
        l1.502-2.522h0.596v4.876h-0.566v-2.069c0-0.794,0-1.361,0.057-1.984h-0.029c-0.227,0.538-0.537,1.077-0.85,1.644l-1.445,2.41
        h-0.652v-4.876H473.13z M479.197,369.269c-0.113-0.028-0.283-0.057-0.566-0.057c-0.596,0-1.105,0.256-1.105,0.907
        c0,0.596,0.51,0.936,1.162,0.936c0.197,0,0.396,0,0.51-0.028V369.269z M476.673,373.635c0.086-0.143,0.143-0.284,0.199-0.426
        c0.199-0.566,0.313-1.247,0.68-1.644c0.113-0.113,0.256-0.199,0.396-0.256v-0.028c-0.566-0.085-1.02-0.51-1.02-1.19
        c0-0.425,0.17-0.765,0.426-0.964c0.283-0.255,0.736-0.396,1.332-0.396c0.396,0,0.793,0.057,1.105,0.113v4.791h-0.596v-2.098h-0.453
        c-0.283,0-0.482,0.057-0.652,0.227c-0.34,0.34-0.453,1.049-0.623,1.53c-0.029,0.113-0.086,0.198-0.143,0.341H476.673z
         M479.197,369.269c-0.113-0.028-0.283-0.057-0.566-0.057c-0.596,0-1.105,0.256-1.105,0.907c0,0.596,0.51,0.936,1.162,0.936
        c0.197,0,0.396,0,0.51-0.028V369.269z M476.673,373.635c0.086-0.143,0.143-0.284,0.199-0.426c0.199-0.566,0.313-1.247,0.68-1.644
        c0.113-0.113,0.256-0.199,0.396-0.256v-0.028c-0.566-0.085-1.02-0.51-1.02-1.19c0-0.425,0.17-0.765,0.426-0.964
        c0.283-0.255,0.736-0.396,1.332-0.396c0.396,0,0.793,0.057,1.105,0.113v4.791h-0.596v-2.098h-0.453
        c-0.283,0-0.482,0.057-0.652,0.227c-0.34,0.34-0.453,1.049-0.623,1.53c-0.029,0.113-0.086,0.198-0.143,0.341H476.673z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

So I tried to access this element like this:

`<img src="../images/"loga.svg#_677331264"" boder="0"/>` where `id=""` comes from here `<g id="_677331264">` path is correct but i'm not sure that's the right way to access svg elements.

Comment: If you want to access an element use <use> from within an <svg> tag.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/

Comment: Okay i tried with `<svg><use xlink:href="../images/loga.svg#_677331264"></use></svg>` doesn't work, or i should use `<symbol></symbol>` around `<g>` element ?

Comment: Please take a look at this SVG: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg You may use the redCat like this: `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat` Also it may be because your SVG is very big and your image is far away in the middle

Comment: A question: do you intend to use your SVG online or as a .svg document?

Comment: @enxaneta as a .svg document `<img src="../images/"loga.svg#_677331264"" boder="0"/>`

Comment: In this case please take a look at my previous comment. try `<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat" />` Please open `cat.svg` to see the code.

Comment: @enxaneta `<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat" />` works perfect, so probably i should set `viewBox` to works with my .svg

Comment: @enxaneta Can you please add an answer instead of using the comments? That way the OP can give proper credit - and perhaps mark the question as answered.